# Pivotting with a strange layout table

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

Here is the layout of the table, please take note of the type a and c which are not appearing on both columns of qA and qB

```
type1   qA  type2  qB
x       10   z    11
y       5    x     3
z       4    c     3
y       3    y     1
z       8    z     5
x       5    x     9
a       3    x     2
```

What is demanded is the sum of types according to qA and qB columns:

```
typ sum(qA) sum(qB) sum(qA)-sum(qB)
x      15      14        1
y       8       4        4
z      12      16       -4
c       0       3       -3
a       3       0        3
```

I can do this by using union all with the query below:

```
SELECT *,qA-qB FROM
(
SELECT typ,sum(qA) qA,SUM(qB) qB
FROM
(
 SELECT type1 typ,SUM(qA) qA,0 qB
 FROM table1 
 GROUP BY type1

 UNION ALL

 SELECT type2 typ,0 qA,SUM(qB) qB
 FROM table1 
 GROUP BY type2    
 ) AS BA GROUP BY typ

) 
 AS T WHERE qA+qB>0
ORDER BY typ
```

But I wonder if there is a better solution for this problem in t-sql.

Answer (score 0):

A natural way to do this would be to start with a table that has all the types.  Then:

```
select t.type, coalesce(a.qa, 0) as qa, coalesce(b.qb, 0) as qb, 
       ( coalesce(a.qa, 0)- coalesce(b.qb, 0) ) as diff
from alltypes t left join
     (select type1, sum(qa) as qa
      from table1
      group by type1
     ) a
     on t.type = a.type1 left join
     (select type2, sum(qb) as qb
      from table1
      group by type2
     ) b
     on t.type = b.type2;
```

You can get the same effect with a `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(a.type1, b.type2) as type,
       coalesce(a.qa, 0) as qa, coalesce(b.qb, 0) as qb, 
       ( coalesce(a.qa, 0)- coalesce(b.qb, 0) ) as diff
from (select type1, sum(qa) as qa
      from table1
      group by type1
     ) a
     on t.type = a.type1 full outer join
     (select type2, sum(qb) as qb
      from table1
      group by type2
     ) b
     on a.type1 = b.type2;
```

You solution using `union all` is also a very reasonable solution.